# In react component, location.href doesnt seem to redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple scenario in which I need to redirect to an external domain in react something like this on change of a switch:

```
handleSwitch={() => {
                location.href = 'https://www.google.com/'; // oldAppUrl;
                    // window.open(oldAppUrl, '_href')
                }}
```

However, this is not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
```

and this should work too, using it in an app:

```
window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
```

If none of these two works it means your handleSwitch function is probably not called, then you should show us some more code to help with the solving.

Comment: Yup prefixing `window. ` worked. `window.location.href = url`  Thank you. Btw do you know the reason why it doesn't take window object by default? I mean location refers to window.location in general. Shouldn't be the case here as well?